# How do I get the weeksOfTheYear as an NSInteger (52 or 53) by using initRecurrenceWithFrequency for iOS? i

Tags: ios, date, calendar

Please help me, I'm stuck!

I am trying to make a simple calendar app and are desperate. I need a value of the weeks of a given year (52 or 53) and I understand that the answer to this question is in using initRecurrenceWithFrequency. But I can't get my code to work!!!! Please help.

/John

---

@AliSoftware

Thannks a lot!

However this code snippet (below) gave me 1 instead of 53. Do you know why? 
BTW my Simulator settings state gregorian, as its calendar.
/John

```
 NSDateComponents *comps = [NSDateComponents alloc];
    [comps setDay:31];
    [comps setMonth:12];
    [comps  setYear:year];

    NSCalendar *usersCalendar =[[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey:NSLocaleCalendar];
    NSDate *date = [usersCalendar dateFromComponents:comps];

    NSDateComponents *weekComps =
    [usersCalendar components:NSWeekCalendarUnit fromDate:date];

    NSInteger totalNumberOfWeeksInThisYear = [weekComps week];
```

Comment: What do you mean by value of the week? Can you show us some code and explain what isn't working?

Comment: I think he means that he wants to answer the question "How many Saturdays have elapsed since January 1 (inclusive)?" for any given date. I believe `initRecurrenceWithFrequency` (a method of `EKRecurrenceRule` in EventKit) is totally unrelated and useless for this purpose; I'd just do it with a few lines of math. But I don't feel like writing out the exact math as an answer right now... :P

Comment: Are you talking Gregorian calendar year or ISO weeks year? If Gregorian then the year always runs to a 53rd week by 1 day & 2 days in leap years.If ISO weeks then there's a bunch of rules by which you could determine the week number of the last week here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date#Last_week

Answer (score 1):

If you need to know which week # of the year is a given date, or any similar stuff (number of weeks in a year, and so on) you should use `NSDateComponents` for that.

You should really read the **[Date and Time Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/DatesAndTimes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000039i)** in Apple Documentation. It explains everything about dates, calendars and date components, the concepts and subtleties (leap years, etc), how the Cocoa classes related to dates and calendars interact with each other and how to use them.

It is really detailed (as every Programming Guide in Apple's documentation, in fact), and **you can't really think about creating a calendar app without reading this documentation**.

*(BTW, I don't see how you question about the weeks of the year would be related to the `initRecurrenceWithFrequency` method of `EKRecurrenceRule` ?!!)*